# Как открыть Excel-документ в отдельном процессе?

Tags: c, .net, excel, vb.net, com

При работе приложения записывается отчёт в Excel. Если при этом параллельно открыт другой документ в Excel, то следующий код закроет и Excel-документ, открытый с помощью COM, и тот файл, который к приложению отношения не имеет:

```
Dim w As Workbook
    For Each w In mExcel.Workbooks
        w.Save()
    Next
 mExcel.Quit()
```

Насколько я понял, погуглив, это особенность Excel 2013 - открывать документы в одном процессе. Подскажите, как же открыть Excel с помощью COM в отдельном процессе? Спасибо!

Comment: Вместо выхода из Excel закрывайте только книгу. Или дополнительно проверяйте, есть-ли еще открытые книги и, если нет, делайте Quit()

Comment: На крайний случай подойдет, но, конечно, хотелось бы открыть в отдельном процессе, если это возможно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте пример из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194565.aspx)

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Sheet") 
xl.Application.Workbooks.Open "newbook.xls"
```

**Добавлено:**

Похоже в 2013 так не получится, если верить ["новшествам версии 2013"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837594.aspx#xl15WhatsNew_SDI). Скорее всего придется следить за количеством открытых книг перед закрытием/выходом_из_приложения

Еще вот что найдено в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn251093.aspx). Открыть Excel отдельным процессом можно, но несколько в противоестественной для Windows манере - через командную строку `excel.exe /x`

Comment: Это и используется, открыввается в одном процессе с предыдущим документом

Comment: А `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` тоже не создает новый экземпляр?

Comment: К сожалению, нет

Comment: Еще вот что найдено в документации. Открыть Excel отдельным процессом можно, но несколько в противоестественной для Windows манере - через командную строку excel.exe /x***********************************************************************************************************************************Я в курсе, сам это находил, но как на счет кода? :) Как провернуть это через COM?

Comment: Ну вот запустить можно через `Process.Start`, а вот как потом получить COM объект это уже не ко мне :) Можно отдельным вопросом тут оформить